# Color chart area multiple colors in Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to recreate a chart using Report Builder that a colleague had in a power point presentation. The chart area is colored differently based on the values of the y-axis. I'm aware that I can write an expression for the colors, but I'm not sure how to reference the y-axis.

Here is what I'm trying to do (pink, yellow, and green): [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to click on the vertical chart axis, find striplines under properties, and change the color interval offset and width.